# Meaning of 成叶 in ランドセル姿の成叶がいるんだぞ

Tags: meaning

I can't understand the meaning of 成叶 in that sentence:

> ランドセル姿の成叶がいるんだぞ!?

Comment: Can you translate the rest of the sentence? Do you have a guess for 成叶?

Comment: Could 成叶 be a person's name?

Answer (score 1):

landoseru sugata no 成叶 ga irun da zo!?  ...that is almost certainly some person's name.  because japanese kanji have so many readings, it's not easy to know what the name might be, unless this is from a known manga/anime/novel with a known character list... but assuming that IS someone's name, this sentence is pretty straightforward:

There's 成叶 ... wearing a child's school bag!?

or possibly: 成叶 will be there wearing a child's school bag, you know!?

(back pack, school bag, ruck sack, etc)

with no other context it's hard to know how exactly the sentence is meant to be conveyed.

doing a quick search, I'm pretty sure those 2 kanji are the name "Kanari" or possibly "Naruka", if they are a name at all.  If not I have no idea what word they might be...  Context would help a little.